# SOAP v1 is failing me

Tags: soap

I am trying to point a php SoapClient at htp://.../api/?wdsl and when I call login, I get:

"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender] DTD are not supported by SOAP in ..."

I have tried adding options to the SoapClient constructor but nothing works.  Any ideas?

Comment: Anther thing that might help is when I catch the error and see what the response is, I see the admin login page spit back as html

Comment: I suspect that it expects XML but is getting HTML and thus throwing an exception.  I have created a proper user and associated it with a proper role so it should be able to login without the admin login page.

Comment: Can you post the code you use?